# Pyramid how to stop projects module names from interfering

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyramid

I am building some projects using pyramid framework, however the submodules within each project are not being imported correctly. For instance, given project structure as below:

```
project1\project1\...
project1\auth\...
project1\other_module\...

project2\project2\...
project2\auth\...
project2\other_module\...
```

So when i try to import

```
from auth.models import User
```

this imports auth from project1, not project2

```
from project2.auth.models import auth
```

also don't work, can't find module

to install a project i ran this

```
python setup.py develop
```

**EDIT**

It is because project1 and project2 are on the python imports path. 
So it finds project1 before project2. 
My only solution was to use a virtual env for each project.
However the question still stands, if I wanted to import specifically from the other project, because I should be able to do this in project1

```
from project2.auth.models import auth
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you never stopped and started the server between the two projects, assuming you started it in `project1`.

You do not "start up" a project with `python setup.py develop`. That is called installing a project.

To start the application, `cd` into `project2`, then run your Pyramid application with `yourpath/to/virtual/environment/bin/pserve development.ini`.

Comment: i started the dev server correctly and everything, its to do with import paths

Comment: OK. Also to clarify, do you always omit the path to your virtualenv when installing your project? I assumed you were just using shorthand, but to be more explicit, you should use `$VENV/bin/python setup.py develop` where $VENV is an environment variable set to the path of your virtualenv. See also Pyramid's documentation on [Creating the Virtual Python Environment](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/install.html#creating-the-virtual-python-environment)